# give number from the database inside the function

Tags: database, typescript, ionic4

I want to give the existing number from the database, inside a function and place this as a value inside the `context.drawImage`, I don't really know how to explain this so pls take a look to the code, then it will be more clear

```
"this is what i have tried to do"
"data = DataBaseService" 

x:IArea;
floors: IFloor;
areas:IArea;
constructor(public data: DatabaseService, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public navCtrl: NavController, public route: Router, public service: DatabaseService) { 
this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.data.GetSingleFloor(this.id).subscribe((floor) => {
  console.log(floor);
  this.floors = floor;
},
(error : HttpErrorResponse) =>{
   this.route.navigate(['/pagenotfound'])
})

this.data.GetArea().subscribe((area) => {
  console.log(area);
  this.areas = area;
  this.x.startX = area.startX
  this.draw(this.floors.blueprint, this.x);
})
}


draw(image:string, coordinateX:IArea){

this.canvas.width = 626;
this.canvas.height = 434;

this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

this.mapSprite.src = image;
 /* "http://antyradar.info/wp-content/uploads/commercial-tumilty-design-commercial-floor-plans.jpg" */
this.Sprite.src = "https://www.lasvegas-waterdelivery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/5gal-cropped.png"

this.context.drawImage(this.mapSprite, 0, 0, 626, 434)
this.context.drawImage(this.Sprite, coordinateX.startX, 161, 12, 20);
this.context.drawImage(this.Sprite, 342, 262, 12, 20);
}


________________________________________________________________
"original code"
constructor(public data: DatabaseService, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public navCtrl: NavController, public route: Router, public service: DatabaseService) { 
this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.data.GetSingleFloor(this.id).subscribe((floor) => {
  console.log(floor);
  this.floors = floor;
  this.draw(this.floors.blueprint);
},
(error : HttpErrorResponse) =>{
   this.route.navigate(['/pagenotfound'])
})

this.data.GetArea().subscribe((area) => {
  console.log(area);
  this.areas = area;
})
}



draw(image:string){

this.canvas.width = 626;
this.canvas.height = 434;

this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

this.mapSprite.src = image;
 /* "http://antyradar.info/wp-content/uploads/commercial-tumilty-design-commercial-floor-plans.jpg" */
this.Sprite.src = "https://www.lasvegas-waterdelivery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/5gal-cropped.png"

this.context.drawImage(this.mapSprite, 0, 0, 626, 434)
this.context.drawImage(this.Sprite, 220, 161, 12, 20);
this.context.drawImage(this.Sprite, 342, 262, 12, 20);
}
```

I expect that `coordinateX` will have the value of `startX` of the database but it gives me property `startX` `undefined`

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you use.  Just a suggestion:  since your DB access is most likely *asynchronous*, consider the possibility that you try to access the value that has not been assigned (returned) yet.

Comment: ↑ What he said ↑ What is your exact error message?

Comment: look at the picture that i added,

Comment: @PM77-1 yes you are right, the data that i was calling wasn't known yet, also i was asking for every area coordinate x while i wanted just the one with the same id as the floor i clicked on so i fixed it liek this


    this.data.GetSingleArea(this.id).subscribe((singleArea) => {
      console.log(singleArea);
      this.x = singleArea;
      console.log(this.x.startX)
      this.draw(this.photo.blueprint, this.x.startX);
    })